# How can I get Unity to automatically add the Sign In With Apple capability when compiling for iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, post-processing, capability, sign-in-with-apple

I have been Googling for hours and trying every variation of this code that I can think of but I haven't been able to get the Sign In With Apple capability to be added automatically.

I have tried examples from this Github project:
https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity/blob/master/AppleAuth/Editor/ProjectCapabilityManagerExtension.cs

I have been following these posts:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-put-ios-entitlements-file-in-a-unity-project.442277/

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1224123/enable-push-notification-in-xcode-project-by-defau.html

An entitlements file without this capability looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And one with the capability looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried to guestimate with this code:

```
proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "SystemCapabilities", "{com.apple.developer.applesignin = [Default];}");
proj.AddCapability(target, PBXCapabilityType.SignInWithApple, relativeDestination, true);
```

But none of these modify the entitlements file or add the capability.

I treid using the ProjectCapabilityManager with this:

```
ProjectCapabilityManager capabilityManager = new ProjectCapabilityManager(buildPath, filename, targetName);
capabilityManager.AddSignInWithApple();
capabilityManager.WriteToFile();
```

But I get an error message in the console saying that access was denied to the buildPath (which was provided by OnPostProcessBuild())

I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Unity3D 5.6.7f and this is what I did to make it work:

- Download XcodeAPI from Unity's official 
  [bitbucket repositry](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/xcodeapi/src/stable/)
- Open CapabilityManager.cs and add the following code

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Add Sign In With Apple capability to the project.
  /// </summary>
  public void AddSignInWithApple()
  {
      var arr = (GetOrCreateEntitlementDoc().root[SignInWithAppleEntitlements.Key] = new PlistElementArray()) as PlistElementArray;
      arr.values.Add(new PlistElementString("Default"));
  }
  ```

  and this

  ```
  internal class SignInWithAppleEntitlements
  {
      internal static readonly string Key = "com.apple.developer.applesignin";
  }
  ```

  Now you can add Sign In With Apple capability with a post-process like this

  ```
  ProjectCapabilityManager projCapManager = new ProjectCapabilityManager(projectPath,"YouAppName.entitlements","Unity-iPhone");
  projCapManager.AddSignInWithApple();
  ```

Comment: I've followed this, but I don't have the SignInWithApple capability enabled for Release and Debug, any idea?

capabilities with postprocess script:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjsaN.png

capabilities enabled manually:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t2OA.png

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, this is my solution and it works.
PS. Unity 2019.4.23, XCode 13.3

```
        var pbxPath = pathToXCode + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

        PBXProject pbxProject = new PBXProject();
        pbxProject.ReadFromFile(pbxPath);

        string targetGuid = pbxProject.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
        pbxProject.SetBuildProperty(targetGuid, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");

        string unityFrameworkGuid = pbxProject.TargetGuidByName("UnityFramework");
        pbxProject.AddFrameworkToProject(unityFrameworkGuid, "AuthenticationServices.framework", true);
        pbxProject.SetBuildProperty(unityFrameworkGuid, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");

        pbxProject.RemoveFrameworkFromProject(targetGuid, AuthenticationServicesFramework);
        File.WriteAllText(pbxPath, pbxProject.WriteToString());

        string fn = "ios.entitlements";
        ProjectCapabilityManager mgr = new ProjectCapabilityManager(pbxPath, fn, "Unity-iPhone");
        mgr.AddSignInWithApple();
        mgr.WriteToFile();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).